# Cross domain API call

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a cross-domain API call in JavaScript.

I have tried angular's $http with JSONP but the API server does not support JSONP, only json.
Using JSONP I get an "unexpected token" error.
Fiddler shows the request was successful and gets the correct json object.
Is there a way to bypass the error and obtain what fiddler gets?

As an alternative I tried CORS with XMLHttpRequest as described [here](http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/how-to-cors/).
The request fails with the usual "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".
Fiddler, however, shows that the request was successful with return code 200.

I don't understand this at all.
Why does fiddler say the return code was 200 but the CORS call fails?

Also, I can access the API url from within my browser (firefox and chrome) without issues. The API is public and requires no authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand this at all. Why does fiddler say the return code was 200 but the CORS call fails?

Because it's the *browser* that enforces the SOP. So you make your request, the server sends back the response, and the browser looks at the response and says "Nope, I'm not allowed to give this code that response."

If the other end doesn't support a CORS request from your origin, and they don't support JSONP, you'll have to go through a proxy: For instance, if your solution has a server, send your request to your *server* and have your server request the data from the remote API, then send it back to you.

> Also, I can access the API url from within my browser (firefox and chrome) without issues.

That's because when you enter an address in the address bar, you're not making an ajax request, and the SOP doesn't apply.

> The API is public and requires no authorization.

Contact them and ask whether they support CORS or JSONP and you've just missed something in the documentation enabling it. But note that there are several public APIs that may be public and open, but not support CORS or JSONP. They may be intended for desktop or server use, not ajax.

Comment: That was helpful, thanks. I'll investigate the proxy option.